# ReflectionTransform gives different colors

Tags: computational-geometry

Consider this example of the cow

```
cow = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}, "GraphicsComplex"];
p = {0, 0, -0.25}
```

Compare the rotation and reflection transformation

```
Row[{
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], cow, 
    GeometricTransformation[cow, ReflectionTransform[{0, 0, 1}, p]]}, 
   ImageSize -> Large, Boxed -> False],
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], cow, 
    GeometricTransformation[cow, 
     RotationTransform[π, {1, 0, 0}, p]]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   Boxed -> False]}]
```

[image]

Here the "Classic" lighting

[image]

So why does the reflected cow have a different color than the rotated cow?

Comment: What happens if you change the settings to `Lighting -> "Classic"`?

Comment: @J.M. The color is still different under `Lighting -> "Classic"`. See the updates.

Comment: Seems like a bug with the way `GraphicsComplex` interacts with `GeometricTransform`, but you can workaround it by using `Normal` to get rid of the complex:  ``Row[{Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], cow, 
    Normal@GeometricTransformation[cow, 
      ReflectionTransform[{0, 0, 1}, p]]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   Boxed -> False], 
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], cow, 
    Normal@GeometricTransformation[cow, 
      RotationTransform[\[Pi], {1, 0, 0}, p]]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   Boxed -> False]}]``

Comment: It looks like the reflection is turning the polygons inside out, so the normals point in. You could  flip them back with `flip[x_] := 
 x /. HoldPattern[VertexNormals -> vn_] :> (VertexNormals -> -vn)`

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks! I will accept it if you would like to write that into an answer.